# Get name of object In String Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, oop, object, processing

How can I get the name of an object as a string in javascript, particulary processing.js, but plain vanilla js is fine if that is what you know best.
Take this object:

```
var obj = {
   w: 200,
   h: 300
};
```

and somehow make a function that returns its name:

```
var nameOfObj = function(obj){
   return *what should go here?*
};
```

so finally i can call this and get the name of my object, *obj*, as a string: "obj"
help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not really possible in any elegant way. If you find yourself needing this, re-structure your code, perhaps have an object of objects, and use the key name as labels (eg `obj` here)

Comment: actually, that is what I have started.This is what it looks like so far:var object = function(x,y,w,h,imageName){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.size = (w+h)/2;
    var img;
    for(var i = 0; i<countProperties(imgs); i++){
        img = imgs[Object.keys(imgs)[i]];
    }
};